# When garbage collection occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
>>>a=6
>>>b=5
>>>c=4
>>>d=c
>>>print(d)
>>>del b
>>># a and b "must be" garbage collection or "maybe" garbage collection
```

a and b maybe Garbage collection or a and b must be Garbage collection ?
How to prove it?

Comment: I honestly can't tell what you are asking. Would you mind adding some context to your question and making the question itself more clear? Preferably using *full* sentences, with verbs e.t.c.?

Answer (score 3):

CPython uses [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). Jython and IronPython use their underlying VM's GC. Having said that, CPython interns small integers, including those used in your code, and therefore those specifically will never be GCed.

Answer (score 3):

Python variables are just names referring to objects. In your example you have three objects, the integers 4, 5 and 6.

The integer 6 is referenced by a, 5 is initially referenced by b, and 4 is referenced by both c and d. Then you call `del(b)`. This removes the reference from the integer 5. So at this point, 6 and 4 are still referenced, while 5 is not.

Exactly *how* garbage collection is handled is an implementation detail.

Now look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object

So the numbers you used in this example will never be garbage collected.

As to when garbage is collected is described in the documentation of [`gc.set_threshold(threshold0, threshold1, threshold2)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold):

> In order to decide when to run, the collector keeps track of the number object allocations and deallocations since the last collection. When the number of allocations minus the number of deallocations exceeds threshold0, collection starts. Initially only generation 0 is examined. If generation 0 has been examined more than threshold1 times since generation 1 has been examined, then generation 1 is examined as well. Similarly, threshold2 controls the number of collections of generation 1 before collecting generation 2.

The standard values for the thresholds are;

```
In [2]: gc.get_threshold()
Out[2]: (700, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

The way garbage collection works is an implementation detail. See also the question “[My class defines `__del__` but it is not called when I delete the object](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#my-class-defines-del-but-it-is-not-called-when-i-delete-the-object)” in the Python FAQ.

In CPython, reference counting is default, this implies that objects will be deleted in the moment the last reference gets deleted. So if you have an object called `a`, which is only referenced in the current scope, `del a` will delete it completely.

However, CPython also maintains a list of cyclic objects, to deal with the special cases where [reference counting fails](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/koans.html#id3141202). You cannot tell when objects which end up in this list will get deleted, but eventually they will.

In other Python implementations, there might be a full garbage collector for *all* objects, so you should never rely on `del a` actually deleting the object. This is also why you should always close file descriptors manually using `.close()` to prevent resources from leaking until the program shuts down.